# Type 'Promise<Test[]>' is not assignable to type Test[], 'T Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<Test[]>'

Tags: angular, angular5

test.component.ts:

```
export class TestcaseComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedDrpDown: Testcase[];

  //event handler for the select element's change event
  selectChangeHandler (event: any) {
    if(event.target.value == "ALL") {
      this.selectedDrpDown = this.getTest(); // error is coming here
    }
  }

}
```

data.service.ts:

```
// Get all Test
getTest(): Promise<Test[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json() as Test[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
 }
```

I need to return selectedDrpDown in event handler of dropdown, how to fix this casting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unwrap the promise from component instead of the service. use `map` function to convert the response into `json`

```
getTest(): Promise<Test[]> {
return this.http.get(this.url)
           .toPromise()
           .catch(this.handleError);
}

selectedDrpDown: Test[];  
if(event.target.value == "ALL"){
           this.getTest()
           .then(response => {
                 this.selectedDrpDown = response as Test[]
            })
}
```

Comment: tried it but getting error   "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'"
used import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; but no luck...i m using angular4

Comment: is there any other way around to solve it,unable to get rid of "map doesn't exist:

Comment: @AnandA remove the map function. check the updated answer.